# Ways to optimize MySQL Table speed

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm currently working on a kpi-dashboard for my employer.

The dashboard displays a variety of KPI coming from a mysql database.
Unfortunately the Queries are very slow, although I tried all optimization recommendations I found on blogs and on Stack Overflow.

The table has about 16.7 Mio Rows.

Here's the Create statement for the **table**:

```
CREATE TABLE `V12` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_id` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `vorgang_id` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sparte_id` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `standort_id` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `verteilungsziel_id` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `haupttyp_id` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `kpi_id` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `value` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `date_idx` (`date_id`),
  KEY `vorgang_idx` (`vorgang_id`),
  KEY `sparte_idx` (`sparte_id`),
  KEY `standort_idx` (`standort_id`),
  KEY `verteilungsziel_idx` (`verteilungsziel_id`),
  KEY `haupttyp_idx` (`haupttyp_id`),
  KEY `kpi_idx` (`kpi_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `date` FOREIGN KEY (`date_id`) REFERENCES `V12_date` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `haupttyp` FOREIGN KEY (`haupttyp_id`) REFERENCES `V12_haupttyp` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `kpi` FOREIGN KEY (`kpi_id`) REFERENCES `V12_kpi` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `sparte` FOREIGN KEY (`sparte_id`) REFERENCES `V12_sparte` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `standort` FOREIGN KEY (`standort_id`) REFERENCES `V12_standort` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `verteilungsziel` FOREIGN KEY (`verteilungsziel_id`) REFERENCES `V12_verteilungsziel` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `vorgang` FOREIGN KEY (`vorgang_id`) REFERENCES `V12_vorgang` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16761713 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

All **referencing tables** are build like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `V12_haupttyp` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `haupttyp_id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `haupttyp_UNIQUE` (`value`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=70 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

My **queries** do look like this:

```
# Time: 141211 19:28:24
# User@Host: dashboard[dashboard] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 1.143774  Lock_time: 0.000075 Rows_sent: 8  Rows_examined: 850
SET timestamp=1418322504;
SELECT `id`, `kpi_id` AS `kpi`,  `date_id` AS `date`, `value` FROM `V12` WHERE `date_id` = '581' AND `vorgang_id` = '2' AND `sparte_id` = '6' AND `standort_id` = '1' AND `verteilungsziel_id` = '2' AND `haupttyp_id` = '16';

# Time: 141211 19:28:33
# User@Host: dashboard[dashboard] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 1.094251  Lock_time: 0.000095 Rows_sent: 56  Rows_examined: 608
SET timestamp=1418322513;
SELECT `id`, `sparte_id` AS `sparte`, `kpi_id` AS `kpi`,  `date_id` AS `date`, `value` FROM `V12` WHERE `date_id` = '581' AND `vorgang_id` = '2' AND `standort_id` = '1' AND `verteilungsziel_id` = '2' AND `haupttyp_id` = '16';

# Time: 141211 19:28:38
# User@Host: dashboard[dashboard] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 4.913999  Lock_time: 0.000098 Rows_sent: 1789  Rows_examined: 1789
SET timestamp=1418322518;
SELECT `id`, `sparte_id` AS `sparte`,  `date_id` AS `date`, `value` FROM `V12` WHERE `vorgang_id` = '2' AND `standort_id` = '1' AND `verteilungsziel_id` = '2' AND `haupttyp_id` = '16' AND `kpi_id` = '4';

# Time: 141211 19:29:48
# User@Host: knorr[knorr] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 4.748257  Lock_time: 0.000134 Rows_sent: 2215  Rows_examined: 2215
SET timestamp=1418322588;
SELECT `id`, `standort_id` AS `standort`,  `date_id` AS `date`, `value` FROM `V12` WHERE `vorgang_id` = '2' AND `sparte_id` = '6' AND `verteilungsziel_id` = '2' AND `haupttyp_id` = '16' AND `kpi_id` = '2';
```

Here is the link to my **MySQL config**:
[Config on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/tkXiKwpL)
Here is a link to a overview of my **v-servers perfomance**:
[lscpu & memory](http://pastebin.com/VSWM27Dx)
Is there something obviously I'm doing wrong?

**Update:**
I split the table into two tables. One big with about 16.6 Mio Rows and another with about 0.1 Mio Rows. I will monitor the behavior of the users and maybe scale the ratio.

Comment: Have you got sufficient indexes on your table?

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your response.Yes, i added indexes. How to i find out if they're sufficient? In the Create statement, you can see them. :) [Example Image](http://imgur.com/iJc9zyR)

Answer (score 0):

One of the first steps you should take is using [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) because knowing how MySQL wants to execute the query is essential for any optimisations you can do. Maybe you're missing indexes, for example.

Comment: Here is the result of the explain statement: [on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bf5exsw2/) I think it uses indexes...